# Authentication Error while connecting to Fedex api

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, soap-client, fedex

I am integrating Fedex API with codeigniter . I downloaded test code and  WSDL files from fed ex website.While integrating, I am getting below error:

```
  PHP_Common initialized

    stdClass Object
   (
[HighestSeverity] => ERROR
[Notifications] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Severity] => ERROR
                [Source] => prof
                [Code] => 1000
                [Message] => Authentication Failed
            )

    )

[Version] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ServiceId] => ship
        [Major] => 23
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

  )



The transaction returned an Error.
Severity: ERROR
Source: prof
Code: 1000
Message: Authentication Failed
```

I am getting this repsonse:

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelopexmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><v23:ProcessShipmentReplyxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23"><v23:HighestSeverityxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">ERROR</v23:HighestSeverity><v23:Notificationsxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23"><v23:Severityxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">ERROR</v23:Severity><v23:Sourcexmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">prof</v23:Source><v23:Codexmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">1000</v23:Code><v23:Messagexmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">AuthenticationFailed</v23:Message></v23:Notifications><v23:Versionxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23"><v23:ServiceIdxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">ship</v23:ServiceId><v23:Majorxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">23</v23:Major><v23:Intermediatexmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">0</v23:Intermediate><v23:Minorxmlns:v23="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v23">0</v23:Minor></v23:Version></v23:ProcessShipmentReply></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Its giving you an 1000 Error. Try looking for the XML/WSDL supporting docs

Comment: The most likely cause of that is you have an extra space before or after your API key or something like that. Or maybe you're trying to use an sandbox API key on the live system. It's telling you it's authentication error, so it's not a programming problem per se.

Comment: Can you please guide me on this whether i am using test url or not??